# Svg getPointAtLength works differently in different browsers any alternative?

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry, point

I am working on svg based application. here user can draw different shapes like rect,circle,line etc. I need to convert these shapes into 'path' and then i need all points in the path.

My solution is working fine for all shapes, except 'circle'. once user finishes the drawing, i convert the circle to 'path' using 'arc'. and when i try to find path point using 'getPointAtLength' , i get different values in different browser. which changes the end result.

[image]

**So far, 'Opera' displaying best result. below is my code. I have three questions:-**

1) How i can fix this?

2) is there any alternative way to find all points in svg path?

3) is there any other way to represent circle in form of path?

jsFiddle Link is http://jsfiddle.net/xfpDA/

```
  <body>
        <script>
            function roundDecimalNumber(number, places) {
                        var place;
                        if (!places)
                                place = 3;
                        else
                                place = places;                        
                        number=parseFloat(number);                        
                        number = number.toFixed(place);
                        number = parseFloat(number);
                        return number;
                }

            function path2Array(node) {
                var pointsArray = new Array();
                var point,tx,ty,cordinatesXY;

                for (var i = 0; i < node.getTotalLength(); i+=0.2) {
                    point = node.getPointAtLength(i);
                     tx=roundDecimalNumber(point.x);
                     ty=roundDecimalNumber(point.y);                   
                     cordinatesXY = {
                        x: tx,
                        y: ty
                    };
                    pointsArray.push(cordinatesXY);
                }
                return pointsArray;
            }
        </script>

        <svg id="svg" width="800" height="600" viewBox="528 139 268 192">
        <path id="square" fill="none" stroke="blue" d="M 636.866, 216.994 a 25.490,29.18 0 1,0 50.981,0 a 25.490,29.180 0 1,0 -50.981,0 z"/>
        </svg>

        <script>
            var svg=document.getElementById('svg');
            var pathSquare=document.getElementById('square');            
            pathPoints=path2Array(pathSquare);
            var d='';
            var point;
            for(var i=0;i<pathPoints.length;i++){
                point=pathPoints[i];
                if(i===0)
                {
                    d='M '+point.x+','+point.y+' L ';                        
                }
                else{
                    d+=point.x+' '+point.y+' ';
                }
            }

        var dynamicSquare=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
        dynamicSquare.setAttribute("d", d);
        dynamicSquare.setAttribute("fill", 'none');
        dynamicSquare.setAttribute("stroke",  'red');
        dynamicSquare.setAttribute("transform",  'matrix(1 0 0 1 100 0)');
        svg.appendChild(dynamicSquare);
        </script>
</body>
```

- i am on ubuntu and firefox version is 28.0

Comment: Interestingly the circles are rendering correctly in FF28.0 on Windows 7. The FF issue seems to be with the linux version...

Comment: Rendering in FF31.0 on ubuntu is fine.

Comment: I get the same annoying issue for FF34.0.5 on Mac. Interestingly enough the problem doesn't occur in FF Developer Version (36.0a2).

Comment: For the record I want to add that this problem does not occur in recent versions of Firefox.